# iOS : Internet connection is available but getting time out error in web service call , same web services are working in android

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

This is my web service call. if i am calling web services continuously, after some time start getting time out error, but internet is available.

Same web services working properly in android

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
request.timeoutInterval = 30;
request.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:finalURL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setValue:@"123456" forHTTPHeaderField:@"header"];

if (parameters != nil) {
    NSMutableData * body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    for (id key  in parameters) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [parameters objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

}

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){


    // This will get the NSURLResponse into NSHTTPURLResponse format
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {

        NSMutableDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog( @"Response = %@",JSON);

        });

    } else {
        NSLog( @"Error = %@",error);

    }


}];
```

Comment: Can you check if you are hitting the correct URL? Also, try hitting the URL and body in postman or some other similar http client and check if its working there

Comment: Change the value of timeoutInterval. I think that default value is 60.

Comment: In postman and in android phone it is working fine.

Comment: Yes default timeoutInterval is 60. but for testing purpose i changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *strServicePath = @"YourURLString";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strServicePath]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary *_params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:yourValue,@"yourKey",nil];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

for (NSString *param in _params) {
    NSMutableString *strPart = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self createPartWithKey:param value:[_params objectForKey:param] boundary:boundary encoding:@"8bit" contentType:@"text/plain" contentFilename:@""]];
    [body appendData:[strPart dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

//You can give your own strProfileImageName                
NSString *strProfileImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_.jpg",@"some_pic",_userID];

if (imageData) {
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=%@\r\n", @"some_pic",strProfileImageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:imageData];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:      [NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
     //Your Code Here

}];
```

Try to implement in this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.
But take so much  time for response in iphone 5.
Working fine in 4.

Comment: Sometimes it does. Try to use 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//Request call here
});

Comment: Used but as compare to android it takes time for response.
Is there any background process problem?

Comment: e.g if calling 3 webs services on different  3 screens . 1st screen web service response is success. and on 2 nd and 3rd screen web service response will be time out error.
Is That is because of response data size or autolyout

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are accessing wrong array.

```
for (id key  in parameters) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [parameters objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
```

parameters in above code seems to be an string array instead of dictionary.

You can use below code instead.

```
[parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _Nonnull key, id _Nonnull obj,BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }];
```